# How to tell the degree of factored polynominal?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

For example you have a polynominal like this:

$$(x^2+1)^2(x-1)^3x^5$$

I know that the degree of $(x^2+1)$ is 2, the degree of $(x-1)$ is $1$ and the degree of $x^5$ is $5$.

I tried to do $(2\cdot 2)\cdot (1\cdot 3)\cdot 5=60$ but the degree is apparently just $12$.

How do I do this?

Comment: The degree of a product is the sum of the degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$x^4\cdot x^3\cdot x^5=x^{4+3+5}=x^{12}$$

indeed recall that for

$$x^n \cdot x^m = x ^{n+m}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you have a fourth degree polynomial and multiply it by a third degree polynomial, the degree of the product is not 12 but 7.